# What is UUID of a wifi network?

Tags: networking

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158747/674,

> First, run
>
> ```
> nmcli c
> ```
>
> This will list your connections, with the first column being the SSID,
>   and the second column being the UUID of the connection.

In its manpage and google, I don't find the differences between UUID, ESSID and BSSID of a network. What are their differences? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[First result](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos-space-apps12.3/network-director/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html)

The ESSID is what is transmitted and what you "see" this is what you will normally connect to for example "Joe's Wi-Fi". As you can guess, I can have five networks called "Joe's Wi-Fi".

The BSSID is the MAC address associated with the Access Point (AP). It is hardware set and should be unique. So of those five "Joe's Wi-Fi" networks, each AP will have it's own BSSID. You *can* alter your AP's MAC address.

From that first result: "ESSID is another way to identify the network." which is a bit vague; however, hopefully the diagram will help:

[image: ESSID]
<sub>(source: [juniper.net](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/images/g041300.gif))</sub>

[UUID](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos-space-apps12.3/network-director/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html) is just a unique ID number. There are not supposed two of the same value.

Comment: Thanks. But still not understand relation and differences between UUID and ESSID/BSSID of a network

Comment: @Tim the only time I've seen UUID used in networking is with `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts/ifcfg-ethX`.

Answer (score 2):

The ESSID of a wifi network is its human-friendly name. It usually identifies the network in order to distinguish it from other wifi networks that may be in range, but it's up to the administrator to choose a meaningful and unique name or not.

The BSSID of a wifi network is its machine-friendly name. It is normally unique (but may not be if the wifi provider is malicious).

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESSID) and [SailorCire's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23797/sailorcire) for more information.

The UUID mentioned here is not a concept related to wifi networks. It's a concept of Network Manager, the program that you're using. Network Manager assigns a unique machine-friendly name (in the form of a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) to each connection. A *connection*, in this context, is a set of configuration parameters that describe the network (its name, its credentials, etc.). Connections also have human-friendly names; the UUID is used to tell apart connections that have the same human-friendly names.

Comment: Thanks. Is BSS  different from ESS? Is ESS a union of more than one BSSes?

Answer (score 1):

UUID stands for "***universally unique identifier***". This is not only used in Wifi/Network configurations.

The article [UUIDs and Linux: Everything you ever need to know](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/) seems a good one to understand what actually this is.

Then, networking in particular, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147964/what-is-the-purpose-of-uuids-for-nics) explains the usage.